# How to remove Drawing Layer menu options?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to remove Drawing layer menu options?

I am using the script below but I want remove the highlighted options in the image below.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
```

I want these only, but the map shows more then three.

```
var RECTANGLE = google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE;
var CIRCLE = google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE;
var POLYGON = google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON;
```

[remove highlighted  option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K3bf.png)

[image]

Comment: Related question: [How to remove square and circle option from DrawingManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701349/how-to-remove-square-and-circle-option-from-drawingmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (easily) remove the hand (if you want to do that, you need to make your own custom control).

To only show the three you want, plus the hand, in the API control only include the ones you want in the drawingModes property of the [drawingControlOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingControlOptions) for the map:

**code snippet: (based off the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools))**

```js
// This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing // parameter when you first load the API. For example: 
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing"> 
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE, google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON, google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
```